# Refresh external pages called by reveal.js using data-background-iframe

Tags: javascript, reveal.js

I'm looking to use reveal.js to run a simple set of dashboards that I would like to loop through.

The loop iis no problem, the issue is that the data-background-iframe data appears to be cached and doesn't update unless the page is refreshed.

Is there a way of forcing reveal.js to fetch an up to date version of whatever is in data-background-iframe when the presentation is on loop?